# At which point in TCP stack do various pieces of information get added to skbuff?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a custom device driver for a custom on-chip packet switch.

Trying to figure out the usage of skbuff data struct.  Mainly where in the stack do particular pieces of information get added?

Here's my understanding of the stack:

1. App creates a socket

   - this creates a socket data struct, and adds IP addr to it
2. App invokes function on socket to send message

   - Switch to kernel
   - Kernel creates skbuff data struct, as prep to enter networking stack
   - kernel adds things to skbuff -- adds pointer to user space start of message, length, and IP addr of target (taking it from
     socket data struct)
   - kernel passes skbuff to the TCP kernel module
   - TCP module asks OS for buffers of 64KB each, copies data from message into the buffers, adjusts pointers in skbuff to point to OS
     supplied buffer

     - Buffers are in kernel addr space
     - For each buffer, a new skbuff is created and added to a list
   - TCP hands list of skbuff structs to the Switch Driver

     - At this point switch device driver has: linked list of skbuff structs, each of which has a pointer to TCP header, pointer to TCP footer, and pointer to a OS buffer that holds the packet payload

Is that all correct?  Mainly the points in the stack at which skbuff gets created, and point at which each piece of information gets added to skbuff

Thanks for the help, clearing this up will be huge.